# Grinding when pulling of in first gear, all other gears fine

Tags: toyota, clutch, manual-transmission, yaris

I have a 2004 toyota yaris. I hear a grinding noise from by the clutch when pulling off in first gear. 
If I lift the clutch up really slowly it doesn't make the noise. I'm just wondering what could be wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Do you feel any vibration in the clutch pedal? If you have a hydraulic clutch, ignore this question. I'm aiming toward a failing throw-out bearing.